# How do I get a list of most recent posts using the facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I log into facebook.com, I can see a list of posts from all my friends in chronological order.

Using the facebook API, how do I get this list of posts?  If I do $facebook->api('me/posts') it returns only the things I have posted.

Comment: To be more precise, if I use https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=... I get the outdated view.  How do I get the latest facebook view?

Comment: What do you mean an outdated view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you are looking for $facebook->api('me/home')?

Comment: Yes, but that provides the outdated view and not how the home looks on facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$facebook->api('me/feed')`.

Comment: That gives me things I have posted, not what is in my news feed

Comment: Considering the fact that the News feed is `is an outdated view, does not reflect the News Feed on facebook.com` - it is the next best thing. Read here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: @user605957, `feed` connection represent `The user's wall.` not only user's latests posts (this is what `posts` connection exists for).